# Update Child table from Parent table in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For my website, I am using ASP.NET Core with EF Core and SQL Server. I have 2 tables, `WorkSchedule` (parent) and `WorkScheduleBid` (child).

I am trying to make it so that when the part-timers select a schedule from the `WorkSchedule` table, the selected `WorkScheduleID` will be passed on to the `WorkScheduleBid` table for the manager to approve.

How should I code the select button in the controller so that when the button is pressed, it will capture the current `WorkScheduleID` and create a new `WorkShiftBidID` with the captured `WorkScheduleID`?

Model:

```
namespace Website.Models
{
    public class WorkScheduleModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid WorkScheduleID { get; set; }

        public DateTime WorkScheduleDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkShiftBidModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid WorkShiftBidID { get; set; }

        public DateTime WSBidDateTime { get; set; }

        public Guid WorkScheduleID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("WorkScheduleID")]
        public WorkScheduleModel WorkSchedules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (To display the data):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> WorkSchedule()
{
        var applicationUserClass = _context.WorkSchedule;
        return View(await applicationUserClass.ToListAsync());
}

public async Task<IActionResult> WorkShiftBid()
{
        var applicationUserClass = _context.WorkShiftBid.Include(w => w.WorkSchedules);
        return View(await applicationUserClass.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Write data back to the _context and then use SaveChanges() to put data back into the database.

Comment: Hi, how will that look like?

Comment: _content is classes in c# that are linked back to the tables in the database using a mapping file (EDMX).  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new controller action that has the WorkScheduleId as a parameter, you can create a new instance of WorkShiftBidModel and save it:

```
WorkShiftBidModel newBid = new WorkShiftBidModel 
{
    WorkScheduleID = workScheduleID, // the parameter of the controller action
    WSBidDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow // Or whatever date you need setting
};
_context.WorkShiftBid.Add(newBid);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```